# I tried to add colors to X-Axis labels without success

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please see my code below. How can I add colors to the x-axis labels?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
title: {
    text: 'Gender Distribution'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']


},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
},
yAxis: [{

    labels: {
        format: '{value} %'
    },

    min: 0,
    max: 60,
    opposite: false
}],

plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
    shared: true
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Male',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7 ]
}, {
    name: 'Female',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2 ]
}]

});
```

enter code here
Edit : format code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example:

```
const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors
const options = {
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: colors[0]
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4],
    type: 'column'
  }]
}
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jun7thnx/

Comment: i want to change color of series. where can i add color

Comment: If you want to change color of series you can specify it in series object.

https://jsfiddle.net/eo2ayab6/

Comment: i want to change male and female colors of x-axis. thanks #stpoa

Comment: can i add exactly colors male:#4472C4 and feamle:#ED7D31

Comment: i'm adding strings but its not working can u please use in jsfiddle and send what i want two colors in male and female please